# Wrapped structs referencing

Tags: go, struct, reference

I am little consfused about value type struct wrapped by pointer type struct.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
  id int
  B
}

func (a *A) setId(val int) {
  a.id = val
}

type B struct {
  name string
}

func (b B) setNameViaValue(val string) {
  b.name = val
}

func (b *B) setNameViaPointer(val string) {
  b.name = val
}

func main() {
    a := new(A)
    a.setId(1)
    a.setNameViaValue("valuename")
    fmt.Println(a)
    a.setNameViaPointer("pointername")
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

I would expect that referencing through pointer type A struct(which addresses concrete memory) that wraps B value type struct will set inner value no matter what kind of refence to B is used (B/*B). This is also related to type definition. Can anyone also explain what is different when I define it like this? Is there any usecase scenario?

```
type A struct {
  id int
  *B
}
```

Comment: The difference between a pointer and a value is the same regardless of where they appear.

Comment: @Adrian Yea. But I mean method referencing. You see that I dont call `a.B.setNameViaValue` but `a.setNameViaValue`. This looks like little bit abstract..

Comment: @bigless - you may want to checkout the go doc on stuct embedding - https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether or not it's a pointer, that's because it's an embedded field.

Comment: @bigless You don't write that, but the compiler rewrites it into exactly that.

Comment: @syllabix My title itself describes my missundrestanding. There is no wrapped but embedded. I completely missed this chapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why doesn't setNameViaValue end up setting the name**

If you declare a method with a value (non-pointer) receiver, then that method cannot "modify" the receiver cause it will actually receive a copy.

That's why the "name" is not set as you expected with the `setNameViaValue` method.

If you want to be able to set the name of B in that way, only `setNameViaPointer` is an option.

You can read more about the differences between method and value receivers here:

https://tour.golang.org/methods/8

**Why can you actually invoke the inner struct methods on the outer struct**

That's because you "embedded" the inner struct in the outer one.

When you include a struct type name without giving it a field name, then all of the "inner" struct methods and fields are "promoted" to the outer one.

That means you can call `a.setNameViaValue` and it will be equivalent to doing `a.B.setNameViaValue`.

**Is there any difference if I embedded as a pointer**

If you define `A` this way:

```
type A struct {
  id int
  *B
}
```

Then:

- The "setNameViaValue" will still not work (that's only related to the method being defined over a value instead of a pointer receiver, it has nothing to do with how `A` references `B`).
- You will need to initialize B explicitly when creating an `A` object, otherwise `*B` will end up being nil. (if you reference it as a value, it will be initialized as an empty `B`)
- You can change what `*B` points to later on (if it was a value, then it will always reference the same "value")